# Why is my QSortFilterProxyModel adding extra blank rows to my TreeView when used with a QStandardItemModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstandarditemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a TreeView and and the model it is using is a QSortFilterProxyModel and the source model of the QSortFilterProxyModel is a QStandardItemModel.

When the Treeview is using QStandardItemModel directly I do not get extra rows but filtering does not work. When I use the filter I get a bunch of empty rows added and I am not sure why.

**ParentFolderModel.cpp** (QStandardItemModel subclass)

(code was adapted from here https://arunpkqt.wordpress.com/2017/01/05/custom-filesystemmodel-display/)

```
#include "parentfoldermodel.h"

ParentFolderModel::ParentFolderModel(QObject *parent)
    :QStandardItemModel(parent)
{
    rootItem = this->invisibleRootItem();
    dirIcon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DirIcon);
    fileIcon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MediaPlay);
    disabledIcon = QApplication::style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DialogIgnoreButton);
}
ParentFolderModel::~ParentFolderModel()
{
}


void ParentFolderModel::buildFileTree(const QString name)
{
    QStandardItem* parent = new QStandardItem(dirIcon, name);
    parent->setAccessibleDescription(name);
    rootItem->appendRow(parent);
    createDirectoryItem(name, parent);
}

void ParentFolderModel::createDirectoryItem(QString dirName, QStandardItem *parentItem)
{
    QDir dir(dirName);
    QFileInfo folderName;
    QStandardItem* child;
    QString fileName, filePath;
    QFileInfoList subFolders = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::Files | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    foreach (folderName, subFolders)
    {
        fileName = folderName.fileName();
        if(folderName.isFile())
        {
            child = new QStandardItem(fileIcon, fileName);
        }

        else child = new QStandardItem(dirIcon, fileName);

        filePath = folderName.filePath();
        child->setEditable(false);
        child->setAccessibleDescription(filePath);
        parentItem->appendRow(child);
        createDirectoryItem(filePath, child);
    }
}
```

**FileFilterModel.cpp** (QSortFilterProxyModel subclass)

```
#include "filefiltermodel.h"

FileFilterModel::FileFilterModel(QObject *parent)
{

}

bool FileFilterModel::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{
    QModelIndex index0 = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, this->filterKeyColumn(), sourceParent);

    if (!index0.isValid())
        return QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(sourceRow, sourceParent);

    if (sourceModel()->data(index0).toString().contains(this->filterRegularExpression()))
        return true;

    int rows = sourceModel()->rowCount(index0);
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        if (filterAcceptsRow(row, index0))
            return true;
    }

     QString key = sourceModel()->data(index0, filterRole()).toString();
     return key.contains(filterRegExp()) ;
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "./ui_mainwindow.h"
// this is where the models are being init
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent): QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
    filemodel = new ParentFolderModel(this);
    fileFilterModel = new FileFilterModel(this);
    fileFilterModel->setSourceModel(filemodel);
    ui->fileTreeView->setModel(fileFilterModel);
    ui->fileTreeView->setHeaderHidden(true);
}

// once the user selects a folder the QStandardItemModel will get populated with the dirs and files
void MainWindow::on_actionManage_Folders_triggered()
{
    ui->progressLabel->setText("Adding folder");
    QString folderName = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this, "Select Folder", QDir::homePath());
    QFuture<void> populate = QtConcurrent::run(this->filemodel, &ParentFolderModel::buildFileTree, folderName);
    watcher.setFuture(populate);
}
```

Comment: You must not modify the gui (and the model) from outside the main thread like you do in `on_actionManage_Folders_triggered()`

Comment: @chehrlic wow just tried updating the model on the main thread and everything works fine thanks! The process or updating the model and filtering is intensive and causes the UI to hand while it's working, is there a way I can not have the UI hang while the model is being updated?

Comment: Short answer: no; Longer answer: You need to calculate in non-Gui (even parallel) threads the underlying data so that the fileModel can provide data instantely. This requires syncing this data acquisition and the FileModel, which is not too difficult though.